# Advantages of getPost over $_POST

Tags: post, yii

Are there any advantages of `Yii::app()->request->getPost()` over `$_POST`?

I feel it makes the code too much object oriented.

Comment: +1 @AliMasudianPour May be Yii haters :-)

Comment: Down-voters gonna Down-vote!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`CHttpRequest::getPost()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getPost-detail) checks if the parameter exists first and if not it returns a default value that you can pass to it.

Here is its actual implementation:

```
public function getPost($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue;
}
```